# А можно ли парсить StackOverflow на русском?

Tags: обсуждение, stackoverflow

Хочу короче слить все вопросы и ответы с нашего сообщества в базу оффлайн.

Стоп. Не ругаться. Можно это сделать? Или забанят :)

Comment: Зачем парсить, если есть официальный готовый архив по лицензии CC-BY-SA 3.0 - https://archive.org/details/stackexchange

Comment: @Nofate это было бы слишком просто)

Comment: @Nofate уважаемый модератор, почему Вы продолжаете писать ответы в комментариях? :)

Comment: Не парсить, а скрейпить

Comment: @alexolut, но это был не ответ, а вопрос. "Зачем?" Я же никак не ответил, можно ли парсить.

Comment: @Nofate, ох уж эти модераторы, даже вопрос зададут лишь бы ответ не писать!

Comment: @Nofate, _"В соответствии с требованиями законодательства доступ к запрашиваемому Интернет-ресурсу 
закрыт"_

Comment: @Grundy сочувствую. У меня пускает.

Comment: @Nofate, так-то меня тоже пускает :-) это Qwertiy там писал :-)

Comment: @Grundy ой, промахнулся. Ну главное, что нас с вами пускает )

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## Можно.

#### С парой оговорок, из-за которых скорее всего не нужно.

Во-первых, как [верно заметил Nofate](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5214/%D0%90-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-stackoverflow-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC#comment19295_5214), контент [уже распространяется на archive.org в форме дампов](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange)*. Поэтому заниматься самостоятельным скрейпингом сайта по меньшей мере неэффективно, может быть даже бессмысленно.

Во-вторых, скрейпинг неэффективен и с точки зрения ресурсопотребления. Выделять структуру разметки, которая может измениться в любой момент... когда можно получить изначально структурированные данные через [API, который у SE ещё как есть](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) и который со временем вряд ли сильно изменится.

Во-третьих, если всё же скрейпить, то можно не всё. В [секции 4 "Restrictions" ("Ограничения") соглашения](https://stackexchange.com/legal) указано следующее:

> (e) copy, download, or scrape any Personal Profile Content for the purpose of indexing software engineers, social recruiting, sourcing, employment-related services, compiling databases of employment solicitation targets, providing content for a hiring platform without the express permission of Stack Exchange or the User.

...вольный перевод, не имеющий юридической силы:

> (e) копировать, скачивать или скрейпить любой контент из личных профилей с целью индексирования разработчиков ПО, социального рекрутинга, сорсинга, для сервисов связанных с трудоустройством, сбора баз данных соискателей, предоставления контента для платформы найма без явного разрешения Stack Exchange или Пользователя.

...короче, запрещено собирать данные об участниках с целью поиска сотрудников, прямо или косвенно.

Хотя это же соглашение оставляет за SE право ограничить вам доступ к сервисам (забанить) без объяснения причин, поэтому никаких гарантий, что вас за какое-то деяние не забанят, дать нельзя.

---

* И есть [sotoki, средство перегона дампов SE в формат OpenZIM](https://github.com/openzim/sotoki) для просмотра через [ПО семейства Kiwix](http://wiki.kiwix.org/wiki/Software/ru), изначально задуманные для содержания слепков баз знаний в оффлайне.

Comment: стоит добавить, что для вытягивания небольших объемов свежих данных (не дампов) есть вполне официальное API: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs

Comment: @PashaPash добавил. Не уверен, что это надо ТСу, но может быть надо кому-то ещё, мало ли...