# API сайта? Можно ли дайджест вопросов/ответов вывесить на локальном ресурсе?

Tags: поддержка

Я попал на этот сайт, поскольку увидел, что здесь задают вопросы и дают ответы в области биоинформатики, пока мало, но надеюсь, тема будет разворачиваться.
У нас с НГ у студентов будет практический курс на эту тему. Существует ли возможность (есть ли API, которое позволяет это сделать) транслировать дайджест вопрос/ответы по заданному тегу (конкретно [биоинформатика](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0)) на локальный ресурс? Понятно, что можно написать парсер, но вдруг что-то уже существует?
**Ну, и моральные аспекты такой трансляции - можно или нет?**

Comment: [api.stackexchange.com](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs)

Comment: Смотря что такое "локальный ресурс". Это видят только студенты одного вуза,или он доступен всему интернету?

Comment: + [А можно ли парсить StackOverflow на русском?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5221/191482)

Comment: Это внутренний боард, снаружи не доступен.

Comment: https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Он на английском. Студенты-медики, хоть и специализируются по онкологии и генетике, но все же плавают в нём.

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку на API. По поводу формального разрешения я правильно понял это как "Всё, что не запрещено, - разрешено"? Мы ведь не собираемся присваивать ничего себе.

Comment: Я думаю, с моральным аспектом все нормально. Сайт ведь для того и сделан, чтобы пользоваться знаниями. Нет принципиальной разницы, использовать для этого API или распечатки на бумаге.

Comment: В чатах Stack Exchange для этих целей пользуются ссылками на RSS-ленты, которые можно найти под соответствующими списками вопросов. Они периодически проверяются, новые записи отправляются в чат.